# How to solve this error: Failed to resolve import "part:@sanity/base/schema-creator" from "schemas/schema.js"

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, sanity

I have the following error:

> plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "part:@sanity/base/schema-creator" from "schemas/schema.js". Does the file exist?

It looks like sanity/base dependency is non existent but every time I go to install it the version is not compatible with React 18.2. Is React 18.2 really not compatible or is there something else probably wrong?

Also it may be worth noting that I got the above error after solving this error: "Failed to resolve import "./schemas" from "sanity.config.js"." What I did was change my import in the sanity.config.js to import {schemaTypes} from './schemas/schema'.

I tried `npm ls @sanity/base` to see if it was there. I also tried `npm install @sanity/base` and it looked like the versions between React 18.2 and Sanity were incompatible.

I would rather not go to later version of React and ReactDom so I was seeing if there was possibly something else going on.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was using version 2 code for version 3 sanity. I migrated everything to the version 3 format. here is the link to the migration setup:https://www.sanity.io/docs/migrating-from-v2.